# How can i read multiple integers using c++'s cin?

Tags: c++

For exemple, i read this from `cin` in c++

```
x // number of cases
// cases
2 3 4  // case 0
5 3 2  // case 1
2 1 5  // case 2
_ _ _ // case x
```

and I need to put each number in a bidimensional array for exemple.

```
G[x][2] , G[x][3], G[x][4]
G[x][5] , G[x][3], G[x][2]
G[x][2] , G[x][1], G[x][5]
```

where `x` is a number of case.

But I dont know how get this.

Comment: show what you have tried.

Comment: You read them one at a time; do you know how to read individual integers?

Comment: Do you have a question or you just want people write code for you?

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file matrix".  Always search first.

Comment: And the better way to store the numbers in 2d array would be declare an array of x *  3 size, and for each entry save them in `G[i][0], G[i][1] and G[i][2]` where `i` goes from `0 to x`

Comment: Im only want how read a integer list without have the numer of integers

Comment: 1) What are you using for your container? How are you ensuring it can hold all the integers in each row? 2) What value should be written to `G[0][2]` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dynamically-allocated array and a loop that reads in an integer for each needed member of the two-dimensional array. `For` loops are standard for this kind of thing, but a `do`...`while` loop with a separately declared/incremented iterator (integer index, actual `std::iterator`, etc...) is also doable, while less than ideal.

To declare a dynamically-allocated array-of-arrays of integers:

```
int width; //The width, or number of "rows", or whatever visualization you prefer.
int height; //The height, or number of "columns", or whatever visualization you prefer.

int** matrix = new int*[width]; //The two-dimensional array, matrix, or whatever you want to call it.
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) matrix[i] = new int[height];
```

Then you'll want to get a integer via `cin` for each index of the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; k < height; j++) {
    std::cin >> matrix[i][j];
  }
}
```

Don't forget to clean up the allocated memory when you're done with it. The rule-of-thumb is one `delete[]` call for each `new` call.

You'll definitely want to do some failbit checking for the `cin` call to ensure an integer is actually provided by the user, but I'll leave that for a different question. Plenty of answers on the topic are available here on SO.